# Fetch data with google script SpreadSheet (ImportHTML)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to fetch information from a web site, there are two queries html:

1. html token to connect
2. html info

I need the session token remains active for the second `importHTML`.

I created this script but bring me the information "2".

For the information of "2" it is necessary to keep connected "1".

```
function getData() {
  var queryString = Math.random();
  var cellFunction = '=IMPORTHTML("https: url ..+ =Token... '+ '","table")';
  var cellFunction2 = '=IMPORTHTML("https://url...'+ '","table")';

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setValue(cellFunction);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A4').setValue(cellFunction2);
}
```

Comment: By definition  google `IMPORTHTML()` does not persist any session info (eg cookies) betweeen calls.  To do what you need you will need to use a web scraping tool - such as scrapy, import.io, webharvest or many many more.